# create/modify a list in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to open a second form, create objects, add them to a list and return the list to the mainform, but I can't see the objects in the list in the mainform.

This is what I have so far.

Mainform:

```
public List<Actor> actorenlijst = new List<Actor>();

public List<Actor> getActoren()
{
    return actorenlijst;
}

public void setActoren(List<Actor> actorlist)
{
    this.actorenlijst = actorlist;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Actor actor in actorenlijst)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(actor.getName());
    } 
}
```

**Form2:**

```
MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
List<Actor> actoren = new List<Actor>();

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actoren = mainform.getActoren();  //Doesn't work!?!
    if (actoren.Count >= 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can't add more than 3 actors.");
    }
    else 
    { 
        actoren.Add(new Actor(tbNaam.Text)); 
    }
    foreach (Actor actor in actoren)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(actor.getName()); //works correctly
    }
    mainform.setActoren(actoren); //Doesn't Work !?!
}
```

When I ask what's inside the list in `Form2`, it tells me what I want, but when I do the same in my mainform, the list is empty.

Any help would be appreciated a lot!!

Comment: `MainForm mainform = new MainForm();` ? This is suspicious. Why are you creating a new MainForm in the secondary form? This instance of MainForm gets its own `actorenlijst`, different from the list on the "real" MainForm that's actually visible. I think your problem is more to do with the way you create/show `Form2`. You need to rearrange that code in order to correctly pass the `MainForm` to it, or pass the `actoren` list back once it's been shown. Can you post that code?

Comment: I cant see an `setActoren` method in `MainForm`.  `getActorenlijst` and `setActorenlijst` could be replaced by a property.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I created a new MainForm because I don't know how to find my "real" mainform in the second form. I use this code to open the second form: `var form2 = new Nieuwe_Actor();
                form2.ShowDialog();` both lines are in a button click

Comment: In your form2 create a constructor who have a parameter of form class.
Do not create a new instance of your mainform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a new `MainForm` won't work, because each instance has its own fields and properties. Setting the `actorenlijst` on the new instance won't change the `actorenlijst` on the other instance.

Instead, you could replace `actoren` on the `Nieuwe_Actor` form with a public property like this:

```
public List<Actor> Actoren { get; set; }
```

Then when you show Form2:

```
var form2 = new Nieuwe_Actor();
form2.Actoren = this.actorenlijst;
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Now both forms have a reference to the *same* list, so there's no need for `setActoren`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! was fighting against this for a few hours now :P